# Embedding web pages dynamically into another web page

Tags: html, ajax, embed

I would like to embed an web page into another web page. Since due to some issues I cannot use a iFrame. I tried with  tag. But it gives some weird problems in IE. The links inside the embedded web pages does not open up in the full body of the window in IE. Is there any solutions to it??
I'm also looking for some ajax based solutions, but I'm not sure whether it will work as my target page is having lots of external javascript files as well as CSS.

Any solutions or ideas will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can save both pages with extension .php and where you want the document inside the other document add this code:

```
    <?php include("myOtherDocument.php"); ?>
```

(The document you are adding should only have the code that belongs there, do not repeat the body tags, head, html, doctype etc...)

You also cannot see the results without using your local server or uploading to a server.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the fact is that I cannot use any server side include as the parent page could be a plain html also.

Comment: Well you're saying iFrames won't work, and then you say you don't think an ajax solution would work either. So how would you do it? iFrame's should work fine. What problems are you having?